# how to use IPython library in eclipse using pydev

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, ipython, pydev

I am trying to use IPython library in eclipse using pydev. The library is imported successfully but I am unable to use its function (I suppose).
Here is the working code sample(running fine in the jupyter notebook):

```
def disp_samples(data_folders, sample_size):
  for folder in data_folders:
    print(folder)
    image_files = os.listdir(folder)
    image_sample = random.sample(image_files, sample_size)
    for image in image_sample:
      image_file = os.path.join(folder, image)
      i = Image(filename=image_file)
      display(i)
```

now the display function is unable to show me the image in eclipse editor while in jupyter I am able to see the images. I've enabled GUI loop integration.
Looking for some answers or workaround

Comment: You're trying to run this in the interactive console? Can you post a full working code (even if a sample) so that I can check here exactly what you have there?

Comment: @FabioZadrozny I've changed the sample code to a working one. Please have a look and let me know if you need to know something.

Comment: It's still no good because I can't run it here (I don't have your data_folders nor sample_size). It should be a complete, standalone example.